# NavigationBar set TitleColor for one View

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swift4, navigationbar

im facing the problem of setting the font-color of the title of one ViewController in swift and resetting it when it disappears. Currently I'm able to set the color from black to white with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
  navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]
  navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}
```

when I try resetting with UIColor.black it doesn't change anything.

when I try to set the whole appearance there is no change at all.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black]
}
```

How can I still achieve this?
Using Xcode 10.0
Swift 4

Comment: Hello Felix! So, which view specifically are you trying to change the color? Could you be more specific? Or even post an image, that would be helpful

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention this. I'm trying to set the color of the title in an UINavigationBar. This color should only be used in one specific ViewController

Comment: Another question: are you using storyboards? If yes, are you setting any tint colors or something related in the .storyboard?

Comment: I'm using the storyboard and I'm setting all colors in Code. in the ViewController with the white Title I need to remove all backgrounds (ShadowImage, BackgroundImage) from the NavigationBar because I need very specific colors.

Comment: when overriding methods from the viewController lifecycle, don't forget to always call the super methods as well.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the code to `viewDidLoad()`, add it into `viewDidAppear(_:)`, i.e

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}
```

Comment: this didn't change anything.
I just tried adding the change to black to the previous ViewController in viewDidAppear(_:) which worked for me. It didn't work in viewWillAppear(_:)

Comment: Exactly..it won’t in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for your help.

I got it working for me with another function:

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    var textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?
    if parent == nil{ // navigating back
        textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]
    }else{
         textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
    }
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}
```

This functions is also called when a view is building up.
This solution worked for me and the colors are already set when the view is displayed.
I'm open for pro/cons responds to this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function viewWillAppear in your code on any view

```
func navigationBarProperties(vc:UIViewController, title:String){
 vc.navigationController!.navigationBar.isHidden = false
 vc.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
 // text color
 vc.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
 // bar color
 vc.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
 let isFont = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica-bold", size: 15)
 vc.navigationItem.title = title
 vc.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) ,NSAttributedStringKey.font: isFont!]
}

override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
 super.viewWillAppear(animated)
 //---nav bar customization----//
 navigationBarProperties(vc: self, title: "Home")
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Subclass `UINavigationController` and assign it to your navigationController:

```
class CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController {

    let usualTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    let customTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]

    private func updateTitleColorIfNeeded() {
        if topViewController is MyCustomViewController {
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = customTextAttributes
        } else {
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = usualTextAttributes
        }
    }

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        updateTitleColorIfNeeded()
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        updateTitleColorIfNeeded()
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

If `MyCustomViewController` is root of the navigation controller, then set it's initial title color in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class MyCustomViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow]
    }
}
```